# &#145; &#147; &#233; == ‘ “ é, but on what encoding/reference?

Tags: encoding, coldfusion, entity, character-reference

I have a ColdFusion script that does:

```
<cfset content = replace(content,"&##147;","""","all")>
```

Which replaces `&147;` by `"`. Google understands this too, if you type `&#145; &#147; &#233;` at its search box its transformed on the [results page](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=%26%23145%3B+%26%23147%3B+%26%23233%3B) to `‘ “ é"`.

If I search for `é` on this [HTML Entity Character Lookup](http://leftlogic.com/lounge/articles/entity-lookup/) page, it'll return `&#233;` to me. But `‘` and `“` doesn't return 145 and 147.

So the question is, what's the numeric reference, character encoding, or whatever else, is being used here by ColdFusion? Where can I see that 145 maps to `‘`, 147 maps to `“` and `233` maps to `é`?

Bonus thanks if someone provides a page listing these characters (since more are replaced on the script).

Edit: Havenard made me realize I was typing the wrong characters because my browser (Opera) was displaying them badly, so now I'm using Firefox to edit this question, and hopefully it'll be clear :)

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Took me a long time but thanks everyone who tried to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: It's *like* this, but not exactly, it's another numeric character reference. In yours, é == %E9 and ' == %27.

Comment: Its because urlencode use hexadecimal values. E9 hex = 233 decimal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with ASP.NET, you can use **HttpUtility** Class as follow:

```
string s = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(content);
```

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpUtility(v=vs.110).aspx